# Unity3D: Access a static objects GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton, gameobject

I'm trying to make a tower defense game. It's 3D but mostly viewed from above (2D).
But if I right-click the mouse the camera can zoom and roam using WASD keys. This works.

However, beside the playing field I have a sidebar where I pick which towers to build and so forth.
But when in zooming/roaming the sidebar becomes useless, so I want to hide it.

I'm trying to do that from the camera-script, so I added a script-component to the sidebar to make it static (accessible from anderswo):

```
using UnityEngine;
public class SideBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static SideBar Instance;
    void OnEnable() { Instance = this; }
}
```

In the camera-controller-script I try the below to hide the sidebar (and everything inside):

```
SideBar.Instance.GameObject.SetActive(false);
```

But that won't compile: CS1061: 'SideBar' does not contain a definition for 'GameObject'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameObject is the name of the class, the actual instance is referenced using lowercase gameObject, so change:

```
SideBar.Instance.GameObject.SetActive(false);
```

to

```
SideBar.Instance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

and you should be fine